# How to add SQL on multiple lines in - SQL.properties file

Tags: java, properties

JEE Project - Separating SQL from code:
I have SQL in my sql.properties file like this .. on 4 lines.

```
emp_sql=select * \  
from employees \  
  where \   
name = 'JON'
```

The loader sees only first line - rest of the lines are being ignored. what am I doing wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure there are no blanks after the `\` backslashes at the end of each line.  A blank in the position cancels the effect of the backslash.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, it's customary to "accept" it by clicking the checkmark at the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the properties file as xml then this multiline issue wont arise. You should use loadFromXML method of java.util.Properties. Please note that this feature is available only from 1.5. Check out the following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29)